# C - Pointer Arithmetic used machine code tester skeleton

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

I have found a similar form of machine code tester across on the web written in C.

The tester uses pointer arithmetic to run a buffer of machine code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"machine code to be executed";

void main() {
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
}
```

Can anyone explain the logic behind the pointer arithmetic of the two
lines presented above?

Comment: This formally invokes UB by casting a pointer to an object to a function-pointer: "*`int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;`*"

Comment: @alk Stop this UB fallacy. Such cast is explictly listed in the standard as a "common extension to the language" and is required to be correct by many (most) platforms. Executing this pointer is another thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the logic behind the pointer arithmetic of the two lines presented above?

**There is no pointer arithmetic.** The code simply declares a variable (`ret`) whose type is a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns an `int`. It sets that variable to point to `code`, which presumably contains the actual bytes of the machine code, and then uses it to make a function call.